# how to prevent tag movement in Django

Tags: html, django, tags

my code is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %}

<h1>hello {{name}} world<h1>

{% endblock %}
```

but i save it. It become

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<h1>hello {{name}} world
    <h1>

        {% endblock %}
```

how to I fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing tag for `<h1></h1>`.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %}

<h1>hello {{name}} world</h1>

{% endblock %}
```